# what is hrtick_clear(rq); in linux scheduler?

Tags: linux, timer, linux-kernel, kernel, scheduler

while going through linux kernel  code inside __scheduler() function I saw hrtick_clear(rq).
Can anyone explain what is this and why it is used?
it seems something related to timer, but unable to proceed further.

Comment: Have you looked at code of this function (`hrtick_clear`)? Because comments above it are pretty clear to me. What do you use to read kernel code?

Answer (score 5):

Classic OS design involves system timer - an entity that ticks at fixed intervals. During each tick, scheduler is called and if process/thread should be switched. But system timer frequency is pretty low (i.e. 1000 HZ, which means once in 1 ms), and if process have only 100us of its timeslice left, it will get extra time (under certain circumstances), while other processes are starve.

However, modern CPUs provide more precision hardware timers like [HPET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Precision_Event_Timer) on Intel, which are provided by [hrtimers](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/timers/hrtimers.txt) subsystem. They can be enabled for be used in scheduler by `CONFIG_SCHED_HRTICK` option.

But if you already called `__schedule()` (i.e. on path of system call), you do not need to call it second time from *hrtimer*, because you already scheduling, so before doing so, `hrtick_clear` disables that *hrtimer*.